# PHP template for Contao CMS won`t work

Tags: php, contao

I´m trying to change a PHP script for me project in Contao with the extension Metamodels. [This](http://phpfiddle.io/fiddle/1069707924) is the source script that should work:

I changed the code like [this](http://phpfiddle.io/fiddle/1036150428).

But I get an Fatal PHP error, did i Missed something? I ´m getting into PHP right now but I´m not so far.

THX

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You missed some quotes in here:

```
echo "<br>======================  ".$arrItem[text][name]."<br>";
```

Change to:

```
echo "<br>======================  ".$arrItem['text']['name']."<br>";
```

Here's what code should look like with the correct namespaces:

```
// echo '<pre>' . $this->showTemplateVars() . '</pre>'; // Zeigt alle Werte aus dem MM an
// ### Tabelle mm_kalender auslesen ###
foreach ($this->data as $arrItem) {
    // ============================================
    // ### Detaildaten aus Fremdtabelle STANDORTE holen ###
    // http://de.contaowiki.org/MetaModels_Beispiel:_Referenced_items

    // Tabelle, in der die gesuchten Informationen stehen
    $objMetaModel = \MetaModels\Factory::byTableName('mm_loesungen');
    // Filterobjekt erzeugen
    $objFilter = $objMetaModel->getEmptyFilter();

    // Einen bestehenden Filter zuordnen
    // $objFilter = $objMetaModel->prepareFilter(10, array());  // 10 = Id des Filters

    // Hier werden in der MM mm_standorte alle Datensätze gesucht, die im Feld 'standort' den
    // Wert $arrItem['raw']['mitarbeiter']['standort'] haben
    $objFilter->addFilterRule(new \MetaModels\Filter\Rules\SearchAttribute($objMetaModel->getAttribute('partner'), $arrItem['raw']['name']['partner'], $objMetaModel->getAvailableLanguages()));

    // Array mit allen gefundenen Datensäten
    $objItems = $objMetaModel->findByFilter($objFilter);

    // ## KONTROLLE ##

    // Ausgabe der gefundenen Datensätze
    foreach ($objItems as $objItem) {
        echo "<br>======================  ".$arrItem['text']['name']."<br>";
        if (!empty($objItem)) {
            $arrName = $objItem->get('name');
            $arrBeschr = $objItem->get('beschreibung');
            $arrAlias = $objItem->get('alias');
        } else {
            $arrName = "???";
            $arrBeschr = "???";
            $arrAlias = "???";
        }
        echo "Name: ".$arrName['name']." | Beschreibung: ".$arrBeschr['beschreibung']." | Alias: ".$arrAlias['alias']."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get the error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MetaModelFactory' not found in /wwwroot.wwwnew/templates/metamodel_partnerpool.html5 on line 10

Comment: It appears naming conventions have changed. See https://github.com/MetaModels/core/blob/contao3/src/system/modules/metamodels/MetaModels/Factory.php

Comment: That the code your using is old, and the classes it references have since changed name/namespace. For example `MetaModelFactory` is now `\MetaModels\Factory`.

Comment: Ok, I will try to change the class name of my template.

Comment: I changed "MetaModelFactory" to "Factory" but its still not working.

Comment: Change it to `\MetaModels\Factory`

Comment: Like this:  $objMetaModel = \MetaModels\Factory::byTableName('mm_loesungen');?

Comment: Yup, that should do it.

Comment: Now I get this error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getEmptyFilter() on null in /wwwroot.wwwnew/templates/metamodel_partnerpool.html5 on line 12

How can I leave the filter for now empty? Because I donwt have one right now.

Comment: Your getting this error because `$objMetaModel = \MetaModels\Factory::byTableName('mm_loesungen');` returned `null`. Looking at the `byTableName()` method, in the link I posted earlier, it's because the query returned nothing. Make sure the table exists and that it's not empty.

Comment: I had to replace an i with an l. -.-
Oh boy now the class "MetaModelFilterRuleSearchAttribute" is missing, how can I figure out, what that class is called now?

Comment: It's this one https://github.com/MetaModels/core/blob/contao3/src/system/modules/metamodels/MetaModels/Filter/Rules/SearchAttribute.php

Comment: Just start at https://github.com/MetaModels/core/tree/contao3/src/system/modules/metamodels/MetaModels and follow the directory structure. It's fairly self explanatory.

Comment: You'll see the namespace at the top of each file.

Comment: Ok, so I just need to replace it with this name: "MetaModels\Filter\Rules"

Comment: Nope, `\MetaModels\Filter\Rules\SearchAttribute`.

Comment: Ah ok, almost, but it doesnt stop, I just put the log in a fiddle: http://phpfiddle.io/fiddle/1754380468

Comment: I would guess that the `'partner'` attribute doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks man, you helped me a lot but I#ve read the tutorial again and I'm kind of stucked because I#m not sure if the script is doing the right thing for me, what I want.

Comment: No problem. You might be better off reading some beginner PHP tutorials first.

Comment: Ok, here is some description of my project.
I've got 2 metamodels "mm_partnerpool" and "mm_loesung". "mm_loesung" got an attribute "solution_provider" which is a select and links to the "name" of "mm_partnerpool".
Because of that select I dont need a select at "mm_partnerpool" that links to "mm_loesung", I dont want to do the same work twise.
The template is for the "mm_partnerpool" table e.g.: If I show the entry "Partner 1", I want to show all the Solutions("mm_loesung") that are relevant to "Partner 1".